# Spring async file upload and processing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to upload file and then read it, everything is working fine, but not when I put `@Async` annotation on the handler method.

I don't want the user to keep waiting until it processes the file. But after putting this annotation I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again` exception. What happens and how do I fix this? As I understand, Spring could be just clearing the file because request-response ends and it cleans it up. But shouldn't `@Async` prevent this?

Sample Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(value = "hello")
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Upload controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/files")
public class FilesController {

    @Inject
    private Upload upload;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addSource(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        upload.process(file);
    }
}
```

Upload service:

```
@Component
public class Upload {

    @Async
    public void process(MultipartFile file) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(new String(IOUtils.readFully(file.getInputStream(), -1, false)));
    }
}
```

And now I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Probably I'm doing something wrong as I couldn't find any error on this and I'd think this is very common use-case.

Comment: Do you make a post request or do you make an ajax request when you upload the file?

Comment: In addition, did you use the @Async annotation in service method or in controller?

Comment: It's a simple POST request (through swagger). I put @Async annotation on service method.

Comment: Can you upload relevant code? It'll help us understand your attempt.

Comment: Ok, I'll upload it as soon as I can (have to simplify first).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You cannot hand over the MultipartFile paramter to your `@Async` Method in the way you do it.

When the `addSource` method ends, the `MultipartFile` runs out of scope and the resource is released. So the access inside your "process" method will fail. You build some kind of a race-condition this way.
Springs `DispatcherServlet` uses `StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart` to cleanup those files. Put a breakpoint there to see when this method gets called upon retun of `addSource(...)`.

You should do the following: Read the entire file into a Buffer inside the `addSource` method. Then pass the buffer to the `process` Method an let `addSource` return.

What you call "...processes the file..." is not "processing" the file, but reading it.

```
@Async
public void process(byte[] bs){
    System.out.println(new String(bs));
    //do some long running processing of bs here
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addSource(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
    upload.process(IOUtils.toByteArray(file));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw I am doing some long processing here, it's just an example.

Comment: Nice explanation! Unfortunately, however, the suggested solution is a littlebit flawed: In enterprise environments, you often have files of sizes you cannot afford to buffer into memory like that. Sadly enough, `InputStreamResource` won't work either.
Your best bet, as far as I could tell so far, is to copy contents to an own temp file (e.g. `File#createTempFile`) which you can clean up at the end of the processing thread.

Comment: Yes @Powerslave your are absolutely right. If you cannot afford buffering in memory you should use a filesystem backed buffer instead (aka a temp-file). I use the in memory approach in the example because it does not create new issues that arise with file handling (access restrictions, necessary cleanup task, etc.).

Comment: To add: the IOUtils is from Apache Commons IO (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)

Comment: Why not do   `file.getBytes()`  instead of  `IOUtils.toByteArray(file)`.