# Can InputStreamResource be used instead of temporary file for async file upload to sftp server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have a `Spring Integration flow` which uploads the files to sftp server asynchronously, files to be uploaded are coming from http endpoint. Initially I faced same problem  as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565597/spring-async-file-upload-and-processing) glad it got solved.

In the same SO thread I found this comment.

> In enterprise environments, you often have files of sizes you cannot afford to buffer into memory like that. Sadly enough, InputStreamResource won't work either. Your best bet, as far as I could tell so far, is to copy contents to an own temp file (e.g. File#createTempFile) which you can clean up at the end of the processing thread.

Currently I'm connecting file inputstream to `InputStreamResource` to get rid of the problem, its working flawlessly. why does the commenter say *InputStreamResource won't work either*, AFAIK `InputStream` never store data in memory

Does the `InputStreamResource`'s inputStream gets closed automatically after file upload?

When we say large file how much of file size are we talking about here. currently in my case 2-5 Mb of files are uploaded to SFTP

Do I really need to care about changing my file upload mechanism to one something like storing in temp folder?

Code Sample:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void sampleEndpoint(@NotEmpty @RequestParam MultipartFile file ) 
  throws IOException {
  Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream());
  sftpFileService.upload(resource);
}
```

SftpFileService Async upload method:

```
@Async
public void upload(Resource resource){
  try{
     messagingGateway.upload(resource);
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2-5 Mb` is probably not a size to worry about. The problem could appear when files are in `1-2Gb` size. Although you may face some out of memory when several concurrent uploads happens to your service.

The `InputStreamResource` is just a decorator around an `InputStream` with `Resource` API for access to the underlying delegating stream. It is not clear how it can work in async environment since `MultipartFile` is deleted in the end of HTTP upload request.

Plus you don't show any code to understand the situation better...

Comment: Suppose if there are 200 concurrent uploads happening at once that also means  that there will be  `fileSize multiplied by 200` memory used? BTW I have added code sample in my question. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like your `messagingGateway.upload()` is an async call... So, that's probably why your `InputStreamResource` solution works. Otherwise I believe it is going to fail because HTTP layer deletes tmp files after getting control back in the end of request...

Comment: You are right. Thanks, I just realized that my async method is not working so `InputStreamResource` worked, However I will apply tmp file mechanism